# Randomly generate a book cover

Tags: covers, random

In order to ensure consistency between the covers of the books in a series, it may be desirable to generate them all in the same way.
For example, this is what the Oxford University Press does.

[image: VSI]
[image: The immune system]

> Is there a way to obtain a similar result in LaTeX?

The title font family appears to be Lithos by Carol Twombly.

Comment: Why have you tagged this `random`?

Comment: Because the cover needs to be generated randomly

Comment: The images appear to be actual geologic cross sections in false color, or the results of some demented artist.  I doubt they are in any way randomly created.

Comment: I would probably just use gradients with randomly generated colors,

Answer (score 3):

One could use fractals and randomize their size, color, ...

---

```tex
% Based on:
% - https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/230228
% - https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/374351
% - https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/447066
% - https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/46281
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\usepackage{eso-pic}
\usepackage{pgffor}
\usepackage{pgf}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\author{Tex Stackexchange}
\title{Random Book Cover}

\pgfmathsetseed{1} % fixed seed for deterministic color, e.g., volume number

\newcommand{\randomcolor}{%
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\R}{rnd}%
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\G}{rnd}%
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\B}{rnd}%
    \definecolor{randomcol}{rgb}{\R,\G,\B}%
}

\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds}
\usetikzlibrary{lindenmayersystems}

\randomcolor%

\newcommand\BackgroundPic{%
\put(0,0){%
\parbox[b][\paperheight]{\paperwidth}{%
\vfill
\centering
\pgfmathsetmacro{\BackgroundPicAngle}{360 * rnd}
\begin{tikzpicture}[l-system={step=1pt, order=5, angle=90}, draw=white, scale=5, rotate=\BackgroundPicAngle, background rectangle/.style={fill=randomcol!20!white}, show background rectangle]
  \pgfdeclarelindenmayersystem{Sierpinski carpet}{
    \rule{F -> F+F-F-FF-F-F-fF}
    \rule{f -> fff}
  }
  \draw l-system [l-system={Sierpinski carpet, axiom=F}];
\end{tikzpicture}
\vfill
}}}
\begin{document}
\AddToShipoutPicture*{\BackgroundPic}

\maketitle
\clearpage
\blindtext[1]
\end{document}
```

[image]
[image]